# pexpect install problem

Tags: python-3.x

i have installed pexpect with the following command "python setup.py install" but when i try to run a program it says "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'". how to settle the matter?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pexpect wasn't ported yet to python 3 (quite a late answer, but still usable for people googling here)

Answer (score 1):

Pexpect has not been ported to python3, and apparently the author has no plans on doing so. 
I tried converting it with the python 2to3 program, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Pexpect does support Python3 according to [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/).

What is your OS? If Windows, then you should use `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn` instead.
More details here: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows